# Limit of callable variables inside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

A very simplified example:

```
n=1
a=n
x=1
y=a+1
while (y-x) <10:
    n+=1
    print(x,y)
    print(n,a)
```

This would go into an endless loop of :

```
x= 1 y= 2
n= 2 a= 1
x= 1 y= 2
n= 3 a= 1
x= 1 y= 2
n= 4 a= 1
x= 1 y= 2
n= 5 a= 1
x= 1 y= 2
n= 6 a= 1
x= 1 y= 2
n= 7 a= 1
```

As you can see, `n` is being updated by the loop and can be called however `a` is not being updated to the updated `n` value. I was wondering why this was. Such is the case if `y` is just `n+1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operations on `int` objects (`+=` here) *always* create a new integer object, it doesn't mutate the previous value. Therefore, the changes to `n` won't be reflected in `a` despite the `a = n` assignment.

You need to rebind `a` to `n` each time you change the value for `n`:

```
while (y-x) <10:
    n += 1
    a = n
```

Comment: thanks for that, you would therefore also have to  reassign `y=a+1` right? Also if the variables being used are linked back to say 20 variables would there be a better way of rewriting the code without having to reassign the 20 variables within the `while` loop?

Comment: @mysteryman yes, you'd need to change `y` too if you need the change to get reflected. There's no trivial way to make a change to an int and then have that change reflected elsewhere. On option would be to use a dictionary and a function to increment the values when required.